# Python list to Cython

Tags: python, arrays, cython

I want to know how to convert normal python list to C list with Cython , process it and return a python list. Like:

Python script:

```
import mymodule

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
len = len(a)
print(mymodule.process(a,len))
```

Cython script (mymodule.pyd):

```
cpdef process(a, int len):
    cdef float y
    for i in range(len):
        y = a[i]
        a[i] = y * 2
    return a
```

I read about MemoryView and many others things but I not really unterstand what happen and a lot of example use Numpy ( I don't want to use it for avoid user of my script download a big package ... anyway I think it's don't work with my software ). I need a really simple example to understand what's happening exactly.

Comment: Why haven't you declared the type of `a`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That's my problem. it's a python array ... I don't know how to declare it as a Cython array or how to convert it. This is a simple example , not really my final script. I want to understand how to , not people convert my script for me :)

Comment: It's not an array, it's a list.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisGallant please don't call Python lists "arrays", it adds confusion.

Comment: Oh , sorry , noobs error. :(

Comment: Is conversion to C array necessary? From [cython docs](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html): "Also, the Python types list, dict, tuple, etc. may be used for static typing"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You'll need to copy the contents of the list to an array explicitly.  For example...

```
cimport cython
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

...

def process(a, int len):

    cdef int *my_ints

    my_ints = <int *>malloc(len(a)*cython.sizeof(int))
    if my_ints is NULL:
        raise MemoryError()

    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        my_ints[i] = a[i]

    with nogil:
        #Once you convert all of your Python types to C types, then you can release the GIL and do the real work
        ...
        free(my_ints)

    #convert back to python return type
    return value
```

Comment: and you convert back to python by doing another loop with the inverse like a[i] = my_ints[i] ? If I understand well. And write my loop with "y = my_ints[i]  my_ints[i] = y * 2" where you put "..." ? Sorry for this question , I'm really new with cython and not really advance in programming. But motivated to learn :)

Comment: okay it's working well. Not good increase in performance (8x) probably probably because it's take alot fo time to convert just for making a simple operation like multiply it by 2. Can you explain me what the lign with malloc doing exactly ? And why use nogil ? Increase in performance ?

Comment: malloc() is a C standard library function to dynamically allocate memory on the heap.  Start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc

Comment: with nogil says that this section of code does not require the Python global interpreter lock because no Python interpreter state is being worked with (python objects, refcounts, etc).  What that allows is true thread parallelization while calls to process() are working in this section of code.  You can read more about the GIL here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: As for working towards increasing performance, I suggest seeing Ian Ozsvald's Pycon 2012 tutorial starting at this point: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Iw9-GckD-gQ#t=3401s  The presentation has information on using cython -a as a tool to help you figure out how the C code is getting generated - this will help you squeeze out further performance improvements.

Comment: Is this still the best solution currently (2020), or does cython provide anything smoother to handle lists from a python function?