# Cython: simple function with 2 lists, what is the fastest way?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, cython

What I want to do - transform my pure Python code into Cython.

Pure Python code:

```
def conflicts(list1,list2):
    numIt = 10
    for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            if i == j and i < numIt:
                return True
    return False
conflicts([1,2,3], [6,9,8])
```

My Cython code so far:

```
cdef char conflicts(int [] list1,int [] list2):
    cdef int numIt = 10
        for i in list1:
            for j in list2:
                if i == j and i < numIt:
                    return True
    return False
conflicts([1,2,3], [6,9,8])
```

Since I am completely new to Cython (and not really a pro in Python) I would like to get some feedback about my transformation. Am I doing the right thing? Is there anything else I should do in order to make the function even faster?

**Update:**

Does anyone know how i can add types in the header of the function for the input (list1, list2)? I tried "int [:]" which compiles without error but when i try to call the function with two lists i get the message "TypeError: 'list' does not have the buffer interface".

Comment: I don't know much about cython, but in regular Python you could improve things quite a bit by using a `set` and doing an intersection (or a bunch of membership tests), rather than iterating over all pairs of items to find matches. The performance will be `O(M+N)` instead of `O(M*N)`.

Comment: How about testing the performance with a profiler? I assume you did this before, so you found out that `confilcts` is not fast enough. So simply do the same with the cython version. If you did not profile, how'd you know that the function is not fast enough? Maybe there is another, much bigger bottle neck to take care of…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"i" and "j" could be declared for optimize your code. First optimization with cython is accomplished using explicit declaration.

You can use

```
cython -a yourcode.py
```

and see some automatic suggestion of possible changes for optimize your python code with cython (yellow lines). You can work with c module generated (work perfect!).

Some handwrite cython optimization:
+ Using type *list* for list1 and list2.
+ *bint* type for *conflicts* functions because that return boolean value.
+ Get lenght of lists because *for* loop requiere end index.
+ Map lists in int arrays (because lists has only integer values).

```
cdef bint conflicts(list list1, list list2):
    cdef int numIt = 10
    cdef int i, j
    cdef int end_index = len(list1)
    cdef int[:] my_list1 = list1
    cdef int[:] my_list2 = list2

    for i in range(end_index):
        for j in range(end_index):
            if my_list1[i] == my_list2[j] and my_list1[i] < numIt:
                return True
    return False
conflicts([1,2,3], [6,9,8])
```

Comment: You were completely right about i and j, didn't even see that:)
I am using the "%%cython -a" command in ipython in order to see the generated code by cython, i guess that is what you meant right?

Comment: When you use -a option, an html page is generated with yellow lines of code, where is suggested put some static definitios. If not yellow lines appears, you are ok and ready to generate c code. Otherwise, cython try to guess those static definitions so you don't need ever write by hand those.

Comment: I still have some yellow lines.. Do you maybe know how i can add static definitions in my first line for the two lists: "def conflicts(list1,list2)" ? I tried "int[:] list1, int[:] list2" but when i call the function i get the message "TypeError: 'list' does not have the buffer interface". Or do i maybe have to transform my two lists before i call the function?

Comment: Just use list for type of list1 and list2. Also, you need say ever end index in for loop (using range for example).  
More complex option is a conversion of list in int array inside your function, as is examplifying [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780007/python-list-to-cython).

Comment: Many thanks for your help, i learned a lot based on your answers :)
Small last question: the function gives me the result but also is giving me an exception: "Exception TypeError: "'list' does not have the buffer interface" in '_cython_magic_73f2048d05377bb2f90492c8fe7aad50.conflicts_cy2' ignored" Anything i can/should do about it?

Comment: You can create a buffer instance (with python core o cython) using array class and create a view instance for that. This is a more complex way (I never had tried with buffer and views).

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, you should be able to get a pretty substantial improvement by changing your algorithm, without messing with cython at all. Your current code is `O(len(list1)*len(list2))`, but you can reduce this to `O(len(list1)+len(list2))` by using a `set`. You can also simplify the code by using the builtin `any` function:

```
def conflicts(list1,list2):
    numIt = 10
    s1 = set(list1)
    return any(x in s1 and x < numIt for x in list2)
```

Depending on how many numbers in each list you expect to be less than 10, you might try moving the `x < numIt` test around a bit to see what is fastest (filtering `list1` before you turn it into a `set`, for instance, or putting `if x < numIt` after the `for` in the generator expression inside `any`).

Comment: Thx for this answer! The issue with that solution is that i already am faster with my python only version. (at least according to %timeit in ipython). I even tried it without the check for numIT and with different sizes of input lists. I guess cython is the optimal thing to do in order to get the fastest results